# Is there a way to get version information rather than "(without test code)" in Eclipse Project Explorer's Maven dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a multiple-module project using STS4/JDK10. When my modules appear in the Maven dependencies of another of my modules, they always show with '(without test code)" rather than a version such as "1.0.0.jar - {repository location}". I have used Run/Maven Install the jar to my Maven repository and I have used deploy to put in my Archiva repository. Some of these modules have Junit tests. Is there a way to resolve the issue?

Am I missing something in my module-info file or my pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not because of you missed anything in pom. In fact this is a feature in eclipse, related to maven.
To see the jar(as you are expecting), follow the below steps:
Right click on module->Maven->Enable Workspace Resolution.

These steps solve you problem.